# Endless fade looping with jQuery image rollover effect

Tags: jquery, fade, rollover-effect

my intension was to replace images with nice fade effect:
i have one image A as background. on mouse hover, image B fadeIn.
on mouse out, image B fadeOut and we can see image A again.
i'm using this code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function() {
            $("img.fade")
                .mouseover(function() { 
                $(this).fadeOut(2000);                          
                })
                .mouseout(function() {
                $(this).fadeIn(2000);                                   
                });
    });     
</script>
```

**but the problem is** that when the user stay on hover, it continue to loop (fadeIn, fadeOut,fadeIn,fadeOut..). i want that when the fade finish it holds. when the user mouse out, just then i want that the new fade will happen.
Thanks!

p.s
this is working code for using 2 images. this is different solution to the problem and i adsd this after my question is resolved.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function() {

  $('img.fade').hover(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr("src").match(/[^\.]+/) + "_over.jpg";
    $(this)
      .animate({opacity:0},0)
      .attr('src',src)
      .stop()
      .animate({opacity:1},1000);
  }, function() {
    var src = $(this).attr("src").replace("_over", "");
    $(this)
      .animate({opacity:0},0)
      .attr('src',src)
      .stop()
      .animate({opacity:1},500);
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `.stop()` http://api.jquery.com/stop/ is a good solution to ur problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
 $(function() {
        $("img.fade")
            .mouseover(function() { 
            $(this).fadeTo('2000', 0);                          
            })
            .mouseout(function() {
            $(this).fadeTo(2000, 1);                                   
            });
});  ​
```

The problem is that the fadeOut() function sets the display property of your element to none, so the DOM thinks that your mouse is no longer interacting with the element, and calls the fadeIn() function. It loops continuously. The fadeTo function changes opacity, but it does not actually make the image go a way. It takes two paramaters, duration and opacity.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me the image disappears once it fades out, which would trigger the mouseout function. Try animating to .01 opacity.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  var img = ['imageA.jpg','imageB.jpg'] 
  $('img.fade').hover(function() {
    $(this)
      .animate({opacity:0},0)
      .attr('src',img[1])
      .stop()
      .animate({opacity:1},1000);
  }, function() {
    $(this)
      .animate({opacity:0},0)
      .attr('src',img[0])
      .stop()
      .animate({opacity:1},1000);
  });
});
```

You can try it **[here](http://jsbin.com/ekaki3)**

**Ref** :  **[.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover)** , **[.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)**

Comment: at the end i used fadeTo and background image, but also your solution is nice and working. i change your code little bit to allow using for all the images in the page - look at my edited question above.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to dynamically switch the image and **REALLY** want to carry on using a background image you could take advantage of event bubbling...

**HTML**:

```
<div class="myClass" style="background: url(imageA.jpg);">
    <img src="imageB.jpg" />
</div>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$('.myClass').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('img').fadeOut(2000);
}, function(){
    $(this).find('img').fadeIn(2000);
})
```

Untested so let us know if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

For others also led here by

```
Google+(Ignorance||rum) = me.
```

mouseenter + mouseleave might help with an odd semi-looping behaviour you thought might work    e.g.

```
var someElements = $('div.event-cell');

            someElements.mouseenter(function () {
                var targets= calEvents.not(this);
                targets.fadeTo(1000, 0.3);
            }).mouseleave(function () {
                var targets = someElements.not(this);
                targets.fadeTo(1000, 1);
            });
```

Seems mouseover and mouseout are more inclusive than you might think e.g. mouseout includes child elements.

```
I think = layman's opinion after rum :)
```

See demo section http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/